# Preventing mutilple method call in a swipe function

Tags: swift

I created a slider, this slider moves from one edge to another and returns to its original position after been dragged. When it gets to the end of the slide, I call a function but the issue I am facing now is that when it moves to the end, the function is called multiple times of which it is supposed to be called just once. how can I make this slider make the call just once instead of multiple times because if the user decides to hold it still at the end, the method would be repeatedly called. bleow is my code so far

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let swipeGesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(acknowledgeSwiped(sender:)))
        swipeImage.addGestureRecognizer(swipeGesture)
        swipeImage.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        swipeGesture.delegate = self as? UIGestureRecognizerDelegate
    }
var startingFrame: CGRect?
    @objc func acknowledgeSwiped(sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
        if let sliderView = sender.view {
            let translation = sender.translation(in: swipeView)
            switch sender.state {
            case .began:
                startingFrame = swipeImage.frame
                fallthrough
            case .changed:
                if let startFrame = startingFrame {

                    var movex = translation.x
                    if movex < -startFrame.origin.x { movex = -startFrame.origin.x }

                    let xMax = swipeView.frame.width - startFrame.origin.x - startFrame.width
                    if movex > xMax {
                        movex = xMax
                        acknowledgeTrip()
                    }

                    var movey = translation.y
                    if movey < -startFrame.origin.y { movey = -startFrame.origin.y }

                    let yMax = swipeView.frame.height - startFrame.origin.y - startFrame.height
                    if movey > yMax {
                        movey = yMax

                    }

                    sliderView.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: movex, y: movey)
                }
            default: // .ended and others:
                UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.1, animations: {
                    sliderView.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
                })
            }
        }
    }
```

any help would be appreciated

Comment: You could disable and enable the gesture recognizer, to cancel the gesture

Comment: kindly provide codes so I can mark as answer if correct pease

Comment: what is this ? -> `swipeGesture.delegate = self as? UIGestureRecognizerDelegate`

Comment: It’s just part of the gesture recognizer setup